# create a form and editing the form but not save (in angular )?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

Hi Friends i have create a form and show it if i click to "Edit Button" the button form will be open and show i edit the form and click the button "Save " this button not effect and not save the data please help me

**Code**

```
// Code goes here

var app = angular.module('theme', []);

app.controller('portfolioController', function($scope) {
  $scope.portofoliosBox = [{
    title: "Finance Projects",
    description: "# of projects Count Sum Aggregate 1"
  }, {
    title: "Marketing Projects",
    description: "# of projects Count Sum Aggregate 2"
  }, {
    title: "Finance Projects",
    description: "# of projects Count Sum Aggregate 3"
  }, {
    title: "Marketing Projects",
    description: "# of projects Count Sum Aggregate 4"
  }, {
    title: "Finance Projects",
    description: "# of projects Count Sum Aggregate 5"
  }];

  $scope.editFormPortFolio = function(portfolioBox) {
    editFormPorfolio = true;
    portfolioBox.title = portfolioBox.title;
    portfolioBox.description = portfolioBox.description;
  }


});
```

**HTML Code**

```
<body ng-app="theme">
    <div ng-controller="portfolioController">
                        <div  ng-repeat="portfolioBox in portofoliosBox">
                        <button ng-click="editFormPorfolio=true" ng-show="!editFormPorfolio">Edit Button</button>
                            <h5 ng-show="!editFormPorfolio">{{portfolioBox.title}}</h5>
                                <p ng-show="!editFormPorfolio">{{portfolioBox.description}}</p>


                                <form ng-show="editFormPorfolio" ng-submit="editFormPortFolio(portfolioBox)">
                                <label class="edit-pencil">
                                    <button>Save</button>
                                    <input type="submit" ng-show />
                                </label>
                                <input type="text" ng-model="portfolioBox.title" />
                                <textarea row="5" cols="" ng-model="portfolioBox.description"></textarea>
                            </form>

                    </div>


  </body>
```

**[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/JS43cijfjrKIPPZpVPDA?p=preview)**

Answer (score 1):

Use "edit" property for portfolioBox

```
portfolioBox.edit = true
```

and when save

```
portfolioBox.edit = false
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/pZSqcTJolkJk7buTGkvf?p=preview